# Submit Add to cart data into new page

Tags: magento-1.9

I just want page which is similar shopping cart page  in which user can't proceed to checkout. Instead of checkout i will create request for quote for product selected item i.e submitted by user from product view page.

If anyone give me idea of how to set data i into new page similar to shopping cart,Then i will create request for quote on that page.

**Updated**

I have create one extra button on product view page i.e request for quote.
This will submit the data in my custom controller but i am getting empty array.
If i will get the selected product option in array, then i will set it to my custom tables.

Comment: you can take data from current quote.

Comment: when the item save in quote , it also display on cart page. Actually i have create two button. see my updated answer